# How can I partition root and home to two different disks?

Tags: fedora, partition, installer-anaconda

As the title states. Basically, I use Fedora and I have two NVME SSDs - 1x 500GB; 1x 1TB -  and, up until now, I've always just gone for the automatic partitioning; I've just selected both drives, chosen to reclaim all the space, and called it a day. However, the former drive is *extremely* much faster than the latter, so I'd like to partition everything "properly".

Here's what I'd like to do:

- Keep personal files on the "slow" drive (e.g. documents, downloads, pictures, videos, Steam games etc.)
- Get the full potential (e.g. boot speeds etc.) of the fastest drive.
- If it's possible without having a performance hit, separate `/home` from the rest of the OS (I guess this point may be the same as bullet point #1?). The reason for this is that it'd be nice to just be able to install the OS without having to nuke `/home` too when a new release drops.

I'm fairly new to Linux, so I'd prefer using a GUI to handle this sort of stuff - the Fedora installer itself.
I've tried following [Fedora's official guide](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/fedora/f35/install-guide/install/Installing_Using_Anaconda/#sect-installation-gui-manual-partitioning) but I think I'm too dumb to understand it.

Comment: 1. Although you can use simlinks to the personal data folders only this is perhaps something hard for newbies. 2. Having the whole `/home` in the slower drive will impact performance because many things like settings have to be read from it, not only your personal files. How much it impacts is for you to find out if you want to do the experiment. Considering #1 and #2 you perhaps should do as the vast majority of the users already does: Use the slower drive solely for your personal files / don't use the system's predefined folders.

Comment: You can do that by creating link to folder that has second drive mounted in other folder in the file system or just make `/etc/fstab` mount your second drive as `/home`.